# MySQL giving error of .NET framework 4.0.30319

Tags: mysql, .net

Currently I have windows 10 and .NET framework 4.8 in my laptop, when I am trying to install MySQL 8.0.23 with 4.8 .NET framework it gives me error that I mentioned below:

MySQLInstallerLauncher.exe - .NET Framework Initialization Error
To run this application, you first must install one of the following version of .NET Framework :v4.0.30319.

Comment: You just need to install updater version of MySql

Comment: What is unclear in the error message? download and install needed component. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/Download/confirmation.aspx?id=17718